# What is correct way to access an Identity Aware Proxy protected GCloud AppEngine URL with dotnet?

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, f#, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I have a GCloud deployed appengine that is protected with Google's identity aware proxy (IAP) and would like to do server to server communication to retrieve a URL from the app using dotnet (F# in this case).  All the google examples hit google apis not appengine pages, and I haven't found any in .Net.   My basic F# below (API calls same as you'd make for C#) manages to set up the service credentials and retrieve token but pulling the home page of the app (which should require no further auth) returns the error below.  I think it's at least partially correct because earlier attempts to provide the Bearer token incorrectly land on the google sign in page rather than the app.   I have added the service account to the list of authorized users.  [The closest google example is in Python](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto) and uses a two step process but the api calls are different to the dotnet library.  Suggestions for debugging or fixes appreciated,

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 401
>   (Unauthorized).) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__27.MoveNext()

```
open Google.Apis.Auth
open Google.Apis.Requests
open Google.Apis.Http
open Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2
open Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
open System.IO
open System
open Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2


open System
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Giraffe.Tasks
open System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

open Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
open Google.Apis.Services
open System.Security.Cryptography
open System.Net.Http.Headers

let test() =

    printfn "inial service account credentials from json"
    use jsonStream = new StreamReader("c:/<path to json credentials>.json")
    let credential = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(jsonStream.BaseStream)

    let t =
        task {
            printfn "Get access token"
            // Is this the right auth_uri?
            let! token = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
            let auth = AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",token)
            credential.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization<-auth

            // This access to an Identity aware proxy protected appengine page access to an Identity aware proxy throws a 401
            let! homePage = credential.HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://<myapp>.appspot.com")
            printfn "%s" homePage
        }
    t.Wait()
    ()
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  Is it the call to `credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync` or `credential.HttpClient.GetStringAsync` ?

Comment: It's the GetStringAsync (web page fetch) that fails.  The former GetAccessTokenForReq.. works and returns a long string looking like a token :)   It seems to work with any string which has me concened the URI may be wrong.

Comment: For what it's worth, an update on my exploration.   The java example code is much more complicated and implies a two phase request.   Get a jwt signed token, then use that to get a google token.  https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap-make-request-java    .  Exploring the APis, there also seems to be a ServiceAccount credential class in the Google OAuth api library and a GoogleCredential class in the Iam library (which also has Jwt token classes).  Unclear which api to request access to.  OAuth, IAm or just Google cloud for my IAP protected AppEngine app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until 5 minutes ago, it was nearly impossible to figure out because there were no .NET samples or docs.  But yes, it *is* possible to make HTTP requests from a .NET application to an appengine site protected by Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP).

We just re-published
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto
so it now contains C# sample code, and a link to a complete sample on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/identity-aware-proxy/IAPClient).

Comment: Thanks guys - really appreciate you coming through on this.     We took your solution and did an F# version too if anyone is interested   https://github.com/demetrixbio/GCP.IapTokenRequest/blob/master/ServiceAccountCredential.Extenstions.fs